# Jquery retrieve multiple emails out of a string

Tags: jquery

I have a string which may contain multiple email addresses, I want to retrieve them and wrap them in a `<a href='mailto: [EMAIL-HERE]'></a>` for each address in a string.

I understand that Regexp's are generally the best way to achieve this. I found a bit of code from another post on here that almost carries this out:

```
function checkIfEmailInString(text) {

        var regExp = /(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))/;
        var matches = regExp.exec(text);

        return matches;
    }
```

But once I find matches in the string, I want to replace the email address with the `<a>` wrapped equivalent. As I said it would need to handle the case where there may be multiple emails addresses in a string and then return the entire string with the emails wrapped. Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**

example string :

```
var string = "john (john@email.com) deals with the fruit and peter Secretary-IUR-Info@email.co.uk is the secretary of information"
```

Comment: Please give an example of the input string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check if this works for you

```
var str = "john (john@email.com) deals with the fruit and peter Secretary-IUR-Info@email.co.uk is the secretary of information";

str = str.replace(/[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+/gi, function(matched){
  return '<a href="mailto:'+matched+'">'+matched+'</a>';
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1hjLpdfm/2/

UPDATE: i noticed that the regex you provided is working as well, you just miss the global flag at the end

```
var regExp = /(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))/g;
```

Comment: Works how I wanted! thanks. I did have to edit it slightly in my code to hold the value in a more public variable as it was coming back as "undefined" otherwise. But other than that it seems to be working fine!